# Rails .js.erb templates no longer work with Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I've just switched my Rails app over to use WebPack to deal with assets etc. It's working well apart from I have some JS templates in my views directory (*.js.erb) . These require jQuery and as jQuery is pulled in as part of my WebPack bundles, it is not working in those templates.

Is there a way to allow those templates to work?

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work in my app by adding the `expose-loader` package, then adding these two lines to my `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
import 'expose-loader?$!jquery';
import 'expose-loader?jQuery!jquery';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in order to make things work you need to include jquery using yarn which works with the latest version of rails.

In Rails 5.1 this is done with the new JavaScript packet manager Yarn which you have to install first

```
sudo apt-get install yarn
```

Then you can use it to install jQuery:

```
yarn add jquery
```

To actually load jquery you have to add this line

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

After installing jquery your js.erb file will start working
Refer this [article](http://samuelmullen.com/articles/embracing-change-rails51-adopts-yarn-webpack-and-the-js-ecosystem/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I'm not using the Asset Pipeline in this app.   I have hurry installed in my node_modules directory but need a way for jquery to be available outside of my web pack packs

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use jquery in .js.erb when I use webpack and without asset pipeline.
(I assume that the Rails is created with something like `$ rails new MyApp --webpack`)

First of, I replace `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` with `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` so we use javascript from `/app/javascript/pack/application.js` instead of `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Add rails-ujs and jquery by running

```
$ yarn add rails-ujs jquery
```

modify /config/webpack/environment.js as following

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

// Add an additional plugin of your choosing : ProvidePlugin
environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

The webpack configuration is reference from [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md)

I make a test page like this...

```
in /app/views/pages/index.html.erb

<div class="index">
  <h1 class="index--title">Index Title</h1>
  <div class="index--jquery-test">
    <%= link_to "jquery test", pages_index_path, remote: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in `/app/views/pages/index.js.erb` it has following code, that will run jquery when the link is clicked

```
$(function(){
  console.log('run <%= "JQuery" %> from .js.erb')
})
```

In `/app/javascript/pack/application.js` import Rails and call `Rails.start()` to allow  the date-remote in the link to work and to make unobtrusive javascript to call index.js.erb file. 
I also try to see if jquery from within pack/application.js file is also work by calling console.log to show a title text that I got from jquery selector `$('.index--title').text()`

```
import Rails from 'rails-ujs'

Rails.start()

$(function() {
  console.log($('.index--title').text())
})
```

When run Rails app at, let say, `http://localhost:3000/pages/index` you should see the 'Index Title' in console windows of the browser. And when click the link you should see 'run JQuery from .js.erb' in the console windows. I hope it works for you.